# Best way to iterate over a multidivisional array using forEach JavaScript Google script

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, foreach

What is the best way to iterate a multidivisional array using forEach JavaScript Google script?

I came up with this.

```
values.forEach(function(row){
  values[0].forEach(function(_,col){
    console.log(row[col])
  });
});
```

While it works I have a feeling there is a better way to write it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate directly over `row`:

```js
values.forEach(function (row) {
  row.forEach(function(col) {
    console.log(col);
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use arrow functions and make it into a one-liner:

```js
values.forEach(row => row.forEach(col => console.log(col)));
```

You could also use a `for..of` loop:

```js
for (const row of values) {
  for (const col of row) {
    console.log(col);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly call [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the inner array:

```js
let values = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
values.forEach(row => row.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x);
}));
```